# Joomla, php GET and redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have joomla 2.5 site, and I have 
http://www.something.com/places?x=target

I would like to have URL like this:
http://www.something.com/places/target

How can I do this?

EDIT:

on .htaccess following works: 
RewriteRule ^places/(.*)$ http://www.something.com/places?x=$1 [L,P,nc]

However it does not work with spaces ('/places/tar get' will only go to '/places?x=tar').  How can I fix that?

EDIT 2:

RewriteRule ^places/([^\ ]*)\ (.*)$ http://www.something.com/places?x=$1\%20$2 [L,P,nc]

RewriteRule ^places/(.*)$ http://www.something.com/places?x=$1 [L,P,nc]

doest the trick. Thank you all!

Comment: Joomla has already good rewrite functionality. Only you have enable it from admistrator.

Comment: Site works otherwise, but I cannot find where to enable that one page to change. It is php GET, not subcategory, so Joomla doesn't do it automatically

Comment: Is the places page a component that you are making? Where will you use the x=target ?

Comment: No. Places is page, in which I run some php code that needs GET value x. It is only used on that page. I can take the value x from url if I could change it to places/value. I just need to know how to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the **places** page belongs to a custom component (not a Joomla! built-in component), you will need to write or adjust the **router.php** file, in the component's directory.

It will need to contain something like:

```
function yourcomponentnameBuildRoute(&$query) {

    $segments       = array();

    if (isset($query["x"])) {  
        $segments[] = $query["x"];  
        unset($query["x"]); 
    }

    return $segments;

}

function yourcomponentnameParseRoute($segments) {

    $vars   = array();
    $count  = count($segments);

    switch($segments[0]) {

        case "target":
            $vars["x"]              = "target";
            break;

    }

    return $vars;

}
```

**UPDATE for your specific case:**

Unfortunately there is no way to do this without a core hack.

So backup your *components/com_content/router.php* file, and then edit it as follows:

Replace the following code (around line 132):

```
if ($view == 'article') {
    if ($advanced) {
        list($tmp, $id) = explode(':', $query['id'], 2);
    }
    else {
        $id = $query['id'];
    }
    $segments[] = $id;
}
unset($query['id']);
unset($query['catid']);
```

with this:

```
if ($view == 'article') {
    if ($advanced) {
        list($tmp, $id) = explode(':', $query['id'], 2);
    }
    else {
        $id = $query['id'];
    }
    if(isset($query['x']) && $query['x']) {
        $segments[] = $query['x'];
    }
    $segments[] = $id;
}

unset($query['x']);
unset($query['id']);
unset($query['catid']);
```

and this code (around line 212):

```
if (!isset($item)) {
    $vars['view']   = $segments[0];
    $vars['id'] = $segments[$count - 1];

    return $vars;
}

// if there is only one segment, then it points to either an article or a category
// we test it first to see if it is a category.  If the id and alias match a category
// then we assume it is a category.  If they don't we assume it is an article
if ($count == 1) {
    // we check to see if an alias is given.  If not, we assume it is an article
    if (strpos($segments[0], ':') === false) {
        $vars['view'] = 'article';
        $vars['id'] = (int)$segments[0];
        return $vars;
    }
```

with this:

```
if (!isset($item)) {
    $vars['view']   = $segments[0];
    $vars['id'] = $segments[$count - 1];
    $vars['x']      = $count >= 2 ? $segments[$count - 2] : NULL;
    return $vars;
}

// if there is only one segment, then it points to either an article or a category
// we test it first to see if it is a category.  If the id and alias match a category
// then we assume it is a category.  If they don't we assume it is an article
if ($count == 1 || ($count == 2 && (int) $segments[0] === 0)) {
    // we check to see if an alias is given.  If not, we assume it is an article
    if (strpos($segments[0], ':') === false) {
        $vars['view'] = 'article';
        $vars['x'] = $count == 2 ? $segments[$count - 2] : NULL;
        $vars['id'] = (int)$segments[$count - 1];
        return $vars;
    }
```

Then in your article's PHP code, you would use:

```
$target = JRequest::getVar("x");
```

I haven't tested it, so I'm not sure if it works. Let me know.

Comment: That's what the question is probably about, but they may want to use the x=target in a custom module, or plugin, and in that case there is no router.php (AFAIK)

Comment: Thank you, but places is not part of component, but rather only an article with php inside of it. My php code needs the value in URL, but the url should be like I described.

Comment: They should be able to use `JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_places&x=target");` anywhere in their code, and Joomla! will use the router.php file to SEF the URL.

Comment: Is it a Joomla! article or a custom PHP page? If it's a PHP page, you would need to include the Joomla! framework files. If it's a Joomla! article, and you're using some custom plugin to include the PHP code, then you would need to modify the router.php of the **com_content** component.

Comment: It would be easy to add it as a SEF parameter, but would be quite hard to parse/decode it, since there are many variables in the **2nd** position for the com_content component already. Can you give some examples on what the **target** value might contain?

Comment: It is joomla article with code in it. Just the places' name, like myplace, central park, office etc. Probably umlauts, and spaces and sign '-' but not numbers.

Comment: Please see my updated answer above, with an answer for your specific scenario. Have not tested the code, but in theory it should work, for a direct article link such as the one in your example.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it works, but I found htaccess route (see edit in main post). Can you help me with space problem?

Comment: You would need to URL encode the parameter. Spaces are not allowed in the URL. You can substitute the space character with **%20**. But it would be best to use hyphens.